# Does there exist a circle with EXACTLY two rational points, no more, no less?

Tags: geometry, circles, rational-numbers

Topic title says it all, I think. Does there exist a circle with EXACTLY two rational points, no more, no less? I know that as soon as it has three rational points, its center must be rational too, therefore an isomorphism with the unit circle yields infintely many (dense) rational points. I have examples with only one and zero rational points, but I'm wondering about the case 2.

I already know that the center must be irrational, because else one rational point on the circle would suffice to yield infinitely many points.

Comment: If your analysis is correct, then doesn't that make *any* circle passing through two rational points but with irrational center a circle of desired properties?

Comment: Yes, I know that but I think I've found an example
The circle $x^2+(y-\pi)^2=\pi^2+1$ has as only rational points (1,0) and (-1,0).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [cut-the-knot.org](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/RationalPointsOnCircle.shtml):

> there are at most two rational points on a circle with irrational
> center. Before proving the result, let's recollect a few fundamental
> facts.
>
> For any pair of rational points, the straight line passing through the
> two may be expressed by an equation with rational (and, hence,
> integer) coefficients. The midpoint of the segment joining two
> rational points is itself a rational point. A line perpendicular to a
> line with slope $\alpha$ has a slope $-1/\alpha$, implying that the slopes of the
> two lines are either both rational or both irrational. Therefore, the
> perpendicular bisector of a segment joining two rational points always
> has an equation with rational coefficients. The solution to a system
> of two linear equations with rational coefficients, if exists, is
> necessarily rational. Which is to say, that if two straight lines that
> are expressed by linear equations with rational coefficients
> intersect, their point of intersection is necessarily rational.
>
> With these preliminaries, we are ready to confront the problem. Assume
> to the contrary there is a circle with irrational center on which
> there are three distinct rational points, say, $P, Q, R$. The
> perpendicular bisectors of $PQ$ and $QR$ would meet at the center of the
> circle which, from the foregoing discussion, would be a rational point
> in contradiction with the conditions of the problem.

So, choose two rational points $P,Q$ and an irrational point $C$ on their perpendicular bisector.  The circle with center $C$ that goes through $P,Q$ answers your question.

Comment: I think the actual answer is hidden in the "so".